# SQLAlchemy autoincrement not inserting correctly

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I created a customer table with autoincrement id, the problem is after id:5 it inserted 151, 152, 153... how this is happening? is there has any way to fix this?

Comment: It is reproduceable , see this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=970b779073372b6f6562f1d858f22a3b)

Comment: Have you been deleting records?

Comment: @Peter no, I didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least five ways this could happen.

1. Someone deliberately inserted a row with id=150. This advances the next auto-increment for the table automatically. I.e. auto-increment will not generate a value less than the greatest id in the table.
2. There were 145 failed INSERTs. By default, InnoDB allocates the next auto-inc value, then tries the INSERT. But it doesn't "undo" the auto-inc if the INSERT fails. So if you have a lot of failed attempts to INSERT rows, for example if they violate other table constraints, then you "lose" auto-inc values. They are allocated, but not used in a row.
3. Some rows were INSERTed with those values between 6 and 150, then subsequently deleted.
4. InnoDB spontaneously "skipped" some values. This can happen. Auto-increment must generate unique values, but it is not guaranteed to generate consecutive values.
5. `auto_increment_increment` was set to 145 temporarily, then reset to 1, its default value. This doesn't happen by accident, it would have been deliberate.

Comment: Is there is any way to avoid this?

Comment: Why do you need to?

Comment: actually, I have to generate a unique id for each customer so I pick the last id then add it to a unique customer id like CS5, CS6 ...

Comment: And is there a roll call of customers, so someone would notice there are no customers CS6 through CS150?

Comment: Yeah, my client will notice.

Comment: Then don't use the built-in auto-increment feature to generate customer id's. Generate them consecutively using some other solution.